# Facebook-like dialog overlay

Tags: android, android-dialog

Anybody knows of any framework/custom class that creates `Dialog` like the one in Facebook app?

e.g.: I click a button and an overlay with arrow pointing to the button will apear.

[image: Facebook screenshot]

Comment: I am asking about the referenced app UI screen shot. I didn't use FB app... so

Comment: As I said, I am working on it.

Comment: i think that may just be an activity inside of a custom built view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if these links helps.. you have to make some UI adjustments ;)

http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/
http://www.chupamobile.com/products/details/502/Quick+Actions/

Good Luck :)